# At what point does becoming normalized vs. star help performance?

Tags: database, performance, database-schema

Let's say I have an ordering system which has a table size of around 50,000 rows and grows by about 100 rows a day. Also, say once an order is placed, I need to store metrics about that order for the next 30 days and report on those metrics on a daily basis (i.e. on day 2, this order had X activations and Y deactivations).

- 1 table called products, which holds the details of the product listing
- 1 table called orders, which holds the order data and product id
- 1 table called metrics, which holds a date field, and order id, and metrics associated.

If I modeled this in a star schema format, I'd design like this:

- FactOrders table, which has 30 days * X orders rows and stores all metadata around the orders, product id, and metrics (each row represents the metrics of a product on a particular day).
- DimProducts table, which stores the product metadata

Does my performance gain from a huge FactOrders table only needing one join to get all relevant information outweigh the fact that I increased by table size by 30x and have an incredible amount of repeated data, vs. the truly normalized model that has one extra join but much smaller tables? Or am I designing this incorrectly for a star schema format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not denormalize something this small to get rid of joins. Index properly instead. Joins are not bad, joins are good. Databases are designed to use them.

Denormalizing is risky for data integrity and may not even be faster due to the much wider size of the tables. IN tables this tiny, it is very unlikely that denormalizing would help.

Comment: Thanks for the response - as a follow up though, then, when do star schemas make more sense - when you're dealing with MUCH larger volumes of data (millions or tens of millions of rows)?

Comment: Almost never when the application is for data entry. But for reporting generally when you are in the tens or hundreds of millions or higher. Certainly it is overkill for anything below a million and we have plenty of databases with many millions of records that are not denormalized. It is a technique of last resort for everything except reporting applications that are only fed from scheduled data imports. And then only when the complex reporting queries are slowing down the other other users.